# Error while trying to capture Image using Android Camera2 API : CaptureRequest contains unconfigured Input/Output Surface

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-camera, android-camera2

I am trying to capture image using Camera2 API of Android. However, I am having this error when I try to add an `ImageReader`'s surface as a listening surface. I have tried looking into the source code of the API and it looks like the error is thrown when a `Surface` cannot be converted into a `Stream`. This can be looked in Android's source in `CaptureRequest.java` near line 738.

My code is following.

```
private fun startCameraSession() {
        val cameraManager = getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
        if (cameraManager.cameraIdList.isEmpty()) {
            // no cameras
            return
        }
        val firstCamera = cameraManager.cameraIdList[1]
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            val toast = Toast(this)
            toast.setText("No Permission Granted!")
            toast.show()
            return
        }
        cameraManager.openCamera(firstCamera, object: CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
            override fun onDisconnected(p0: CameraDevice) { }
            override fun onError(p0: CameraDevice, p1: Int) { }

            override fun onOpened(cameraDevice: CameraDevice) {
                // use the camera
                val cameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.id)

                cameraCharacteristics[CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP]?.let { streamConfigurationMap ->
                    streamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)?.let { yuvSizes ->
                        val previewSize = yuvSizes.last()
                        // cont.
                        val displayRotation = windowManager.defaultDisplay.rotation
                        val swappedDimensions = areDimensionsSwapped(displayRotation, cameraCharacteristics)
                        // swap width and height if needed
                        val rotatedPreviewWidth = if (swappedDimensions) previewSize.height else previewSize.width
                        val rotatedPreviewHeight = if (swappedDimensions) previewSize.width else previewSize.height

                        surfaceView.holder.setFixedSize(rotatedPreviewWidth, rotatedPreviewHeight)

                        // Configure Image Reader
                        val imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(rotatedPreviewWidth, rotatedPreviewHeight,
                            ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 2)
                        imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({
                            val previewSurface = surfaceView.holder.surface

                            imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({
                                Log.d("camera","setOnImageAvailableListener")
                                imageReader.acquireLatestImage()?.let { image ->
                                    Log.d("camera","acquireLatestImage")
                                }
                            }, Handler { true })

                        }, Handler { true })

                        val previewSurface = surfaceView.holder.surface
                        val recordingSurface = imageReader.surface

                        val captureCallback = object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback()
                        {
                            override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {}

                            override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                                // session configured
                                val previewRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(TEMPLATE_PREVIEW).apply {
                                    addTarget(recordingSurface)
                                }
                                session.setRepeatingRequest(
                                    previewRequestBuilder.build(),
                                    object: CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {},
                                    Handler { true }
                                )
                            }
                        }
                        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(mutableListOf(previewSurface), captureCallback, Handler { true })
                    }
                }
            }
        }, Handler { true })
    }
```

The following is the stack trace for the error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.security.camerapractice, PID: 15957
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CaptureRequest contains unconfigured Input/Output Surface!
        at android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest.convertSurfaceToStreamId(CaptureRequest.java:738)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.submitCaptureRequest(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1179)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.setRepeatingRequest(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1227)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.setRepeatingRequest(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:312)
        at com.security.camerapractice.MainActivity$startCameraSession$1$onOpened$$inlined$let$lambda$2.onConfigured(MainActivity.kt:179)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CallbackProxies$SessionStateCallbackProxy.lambda$onConfigured$0$CallbackProxies$SessionStateCallbackProxy(CallbackProxies.java:53)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.-$$Lambda$CallbackProxies$SessionStateCallbackProxy$soW0qC12Osypoky6AfL3P2-TeDw.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: I can't tell from your snippet, but are you waiting for `SurfaceView`'s surface to be ready before passing it to the camera? SurfaceView's surface can only be used between its [surfaceCreated()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback#surfaceCreated(android.view.SurfaceHolder)) and [surfaceDestroyed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback#surfaceDestroyed(android.view.SurfaceHolder)) callbacks.

Comment: It is not a SurfaceView's Surface. It is a Surface of ImageReader.

Comment: From the snippet, it also seems you're building the capture session with the wrong target, you're passing in the surfaceView's surface but you're building the capture request with the imageReader's surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Husayn in his comments, the wrong target was being passed to the capture request. The following changes solved the problem.

```
cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(mutableListOf(recordingSurface), captureCallback, Handler { true })
```